# AngularJS: Change directive attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a custom directive which does validation, based on the directive attribute value.

e.g.: `<input type="text" ng-my-validate="onlyletters" />`

I want to change the `onlyletters` value to `onlynumbers` on the fly and want to the directive change it's validation behaviour because of that.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why not HTML5's `pattern` or AngularJS's `ng-pattern`?

Comment: onlyletters is just an example. My real validation rules are Brazilian document numbers.

Comment: How is your directive set up? I don't see why this wouldn't be very easy to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>You should be using [attribute `$observers`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$compile.directive.Attributes#$observe).</s>

UPDATE: @MatthewGreen is correct. I overlooked the fact that you are not using a interpolated value. In this case consider using a `$watcher` with plain jQuery attribute reading:

```js
angular.module('mod', [])
  .directive('ngMyValidate', function() {
    return {
      link: function(scope, elm, attr) {
        scope.$watch(function() {
          return elm.attr('ng-my-validate');
        }, function(value) {
          console.log('attribute changed:', value);
        });
      }
    };
 });
```

Thanks @MatthewGreen!

Comment: The attribute doesn't appear to use interpolation though so I'm not sure how this would help them.

Comment: Good catch @MatthewGreen. Updated my answer.